# g++ compiler gives me errors with -std=c++11 flag, but it compiles fine with -std=gnu++11. what does this mean?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

I'm maintaining an old server at work, which is running on `CentOS6(gcc (GCC) 4.4.7, C++98)`
and I was trying to migrate it to `CentOS7(gcc (GCC) 4.8.5)` with C++11.

At first, I tried to compile with a flag, `-std=c++11` but it gaved me a lot of error like below.

```
`In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/x86intrin.h:30:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/x86_64-redhat-linux/bits/opt_random.h:33,
                 ...
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/mmintrin.h: In function ‘__m64_mm_cvtsi32_si64(int)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/mmintrin.h:61:54: error: can’t convert between vector values of different size
   return (__m64) __builtin_ia32_vec_init_v2si (__i, 0);
                                                      ^
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/mmintrin.h: In function ‘int _mm_cvtsi64_si32(__m64)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.5/include/mmintrin.h:104:53: error: cannot convert ‘__m64 {aka int}’ to ‘__vector(2) int’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘int __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si(__vector(2) int, int)’
   return __builtin_ia32_vec_ext_v2si ((__v2si)__i, 0);`
```

Somehow, I encountered about using a flag, `-std=gnu++11` and it worked fine.

What can I assume with this?
Does this mean that the old server code is somehow using gnu extension or whatever?

Comment: Yes, it means just that. It's trying casts which are illegal in pure C++, and that's expected when you are using any of the intrinsics.

Comment: Possibly OT: GCC 4 is quite an old version. You can install much newer versions in CentOS; look for _Developer Toolset_: https://www.softwarecollections.org/en/scls/rhscl/devtoolset-7/.

Comment: The double underscore is a hint that you're using compiler extensions. Those are reserved names.

Comment: A bit odd that you have GCC 4.8.5 commingled with GCC 4.8.2.  (Maybe the setup is correct, and it just seems a bit odd to me.). GCC 4.8.5 was released June 23, 2015.  GCC 4.8.2 was released October 16, 2013.  GCC 11.2 was released July 28, 2021 — but I don't know if that works for CentOS7.  The current version of CentOS is 8.4.2105 (June 3, 2021).

Comment: Thanks all. @Eljay I don't know why but the department at work in charge of infra provides servers in that environments. (All I can choose is a version of CentOS and they recommend 7 for developers for the reason 8 has earlier EOL than 7 and it seems like they don't really care about things about C++ coz most of them in this corp use Java mainly these days.)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you might encounter errors with -std=c++11 but not with -std=gnu++11 is that your code may be using certain GNU extensions that are not supported in the strict C++11 mode. By enabling the -std=gnu++11 flag, you allow the compiler to use those extensions and avoid the related errors.

It's worth noting that using GNU extensions makes your code less portable, as they may not be supported by other compilers. If you want your code to adhere strictly to the C++11 standard, it's generally recommended to use the -std=c++11 flag. However, if you rely on certain GNU extensions or are specifically targeting the GCC compiler, then using -std=gnu++11 may be appropriate.